# Flexslider smoothHeight not working

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress, flexslider

There is loads of white space above and below my images when I resize the window. I have tried using smoothHeight: true but all this does is set the container to 500px. Isn't this supposed to make the height dynamic? I know both the images are different sizes in my slider. but still the first image should have no white space. heres my code:

```
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
            $(document).ready(function() {
                $('.flexslider').flexslider({
                    animation: "slide",
                    animationLoop: true,
                    slideshow: true,                
                    slideshowSpeed: 4000,           
                    animationSpeed: 1000,
                    randomize: false,
                    pauseOnHover: true,
                    pauseOnAction: false,
                    controlNav: false,
                    directionNav: true,
                    smoothHeight: true
                });
            });
        </script>


<?php if( have_rows('slider') ): ?>
                    <div class="flexslider no_border">
                        <ul class="slides">
                            <?php while( have_rows('slider') ): the_row(); 

                                // vars
                                $image = get_sub_field('image');
                                $content = get_sub_field('content');
                                $link = get_sub_field('link');

                                ?>

                                <li class="slide">

                                    <?php if( $link ): ?>
                                        <a href="<?php echo $link; ?>">
                                    <?php endif; ?>

                                        <img class="slider_images" src="<?php echo $image['url']; ?>" alt="<?php echo $image['alt'] ?>" />

                                    <?php if( $link ): ?>
                                        </a>
                                    <?php endif; ?>

                                    <?php echo $content; ?>
                                </li>
                            <?php endwhile; ?>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                <?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: you might try removing `position: absolute` from the images. The parent won't know the height of the image as long as you're using absolute positioning.

Comment: Thats awesome thanks mate. If you put it up as an actual answer I'll accept it

Comment: oh cool, did that work?

Comment: I thought it was perfect but it still leaves white space under the image. But its a start thanks

Comment: It leaves the same amount of white space? Or less? Did you update your website? If you gave us a working demo ([mcve]), I could troubleshoot a lot better.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your images are set to `position: absolute` which removes them from the flow of the page. Meaning other elements on the page don't know how much space it occupies. Flexslider resizes things based on the dimensions of the individual slides, which in your case is `li.slide`. And since the image in `li.slide` is `absolute`, `li.slide`'s height will not match the size of the content inside of it (your images).

Try just removing `position: absolute` from the image and see if that allows it to scale.

Comment: Thanks it removed most the white space. The rest I removed by removing one of my height styles